# two nested map data verification at each record level in java/webdriver

Tags: java, webdriver

I have a scenario where i need to compare the UI data with database.

In UI i have n number of data with n fields.

so i want to compare all n number of data and each data n fields with database.

so for that i stored UI data in nested map and the same way i stored the database data in nested map now i need to compare each record and each field of record. can anyone please suggest how to do it.

UI nested map data looks like -
{1={1=Edit, 2=Click to view report options, 3=123456}, 2={1=EMPTY, 2=Click to view report options, 3=6000792}, 3={1=EMPTY, 2=Click to view report options, 3=6000791}}

DB nested map data looks like -
{1={1=Edit, 2=Click to view report options, 3=123456}, 2={1=EMPTY, 2=Click to view report options, 3=6000792}, 3={1=EMPTY, 2=Click to view report options, 3=6000791},4={1=EMPTY, 2=Click to view report options, 3=6011791},5={1=EMPTY, 2=Click to view report options, 3=6011792}}

i am using JAVA/WebDriver language. since i am new in java side so not sure how to implement this.
pls suggest.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the [Guava library](https://github.com/google/guava) from Google to do that. That library comes with a handy method to compare maps: `Maps.difference(mapA, mapB)`

Here's an example of what that would look like (I've copied your sample data into two `ImmutableMap` objects for simplicity. Note that this will work with "normal" maps just as well of course):

```
ImmutableMap<Integer, ImmutableMap<Integer, String>> uiMap = ImmutableMap.<Integer, ImmutableMap<Integer, String>>of(
  1, ImmutableMap.<Integer, String>of(1, "Edit", 2, "Click to view report options", 3, "123456"),
  2, ImmutableMap.<Integer, String>of(1, "EMPTY", 2, "Click to view report options", 3, "6000792"),
  3, ImmutableMap.<Integer, String>of(1, "EMPTY", 2, "Click to view report options", 3, "6000791"));

ImmutableMap<Integer, ImmutableMap<Integer, String>> dbMap = ImmutableMap.<Integer, ImmutableMap<Integer, String>>of(
  1, ImmutableMap.<Integer, String>of(1, "Edit", 2, "Click to view report options", 3, "123456"),
  2, ImmutableMap.<Integer, String>of(1, "EMPTY", 2, "Click to view report options", 3, "6000792"),
  3, ImmutableMap.<Integer, String>of(1, "EMPTY", 2, "Click to view report options", 3, "6000791"),
  4, ImmutableMap.<Integer, String>of(1, "EMPTY", 2, "Click to view report options", 3, "6011791"),
  5, ImmutableMap.<Integer, String>of(1, "EMPTY", 2, "Click to view report options", 3, "6011792"));

System.out.println(Maps.difference(uiMap, dbMap));
```

Which will give you the following output:

```
not equal: only on right={4={1=EMPTY, 2=Click to view report options, 3=6011791}, 5={1=EMPTY, 2=Click to view report options, 3=6011792}}
```